# Android local search

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a local search in my activity. I've added an appropriate intent filter and metadata tag to manifest file but if I click Search button it invokes standard android search box. What's my problem?

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nixsolutions.invertigation.android.dataprovider"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">


    <provider
        android:name="NoteProvider"
            android:authorities="com.nixsolutions.investigation.android.NoteProvider">
    </provider>
    <activity
        android:name="NotesList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:label="Custom search"
android:hint="Custom hint"
android:searchMode="showSearchLabelAsBadge"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need an activity flagged (on application level) as the one that is offering the search, via:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".LoremSearch" />
```

(substituting in the proper value for `android:value`)

E.g.:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:debuggable="true"  android:allowBackup="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".MySearchActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".MySearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

The way you have specified for an activity only, only enables search within that activity.
Only adding the meta-data tag at application level enables search for all activities.

[See here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Search/Lorem/) for a complete search project.

Comment: Added <meta-data android:name = "android.app.default_searchable" android:value = "NotesList"></meta-data>. Still doesn't work. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private List<MyBillResponseItem> itemList;
    private List<MyBillResponseItem> mainitemList;
    private List<MyBillResponseItem> selecteditemList;

  itemList = new ArrayList<MyBillResponseItem>();
        selecteditemList = new ArrayList<MyBillResponseItem>();
        mainitemList = new ArrayList<MyBillResponseItem>(); 

void filter(String text) {
        itemList.clear();
        Log.d("tag ::", "mainitemList 02" + mainitemList.size());
        for (MyBillResponseItem d : mainitemList) {
            if (d.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                itemList.add(d);
            }
            Log.d("tag ::", "itemList 02" + itemList.size());
        }
        //update recyclerview
        myBillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void GetBillingList(Date newFromDate, Date newToDate) {
        itemList.clear();
        final AlertDialog dialog = Utils.dialogProgress(getActivity());
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        GetMyBillingReqEnvelope requestEnvelope = new GetMyBillingReqEnvelope();
        final String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Log.d("tag ::", "device id :" + deviceId);
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df.parse(formattedDate);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String newFromDate1 = sdf.format(newFromDate);
        String newToDate1 = sdf.format(newToDate);
        RequestHeader requestHeader = new RequestHeader(Helper.getStringValue(getActivity(), "mobile"),
                Helper.getStringValue(getActivity(), "password"), Helper.getStringValue(getActivity(), "fcmToken"),
                Helper.getStringValue(getActivity(), "deviceId"), newFromDate1, newToDate1, empid);
        GetMyBillingReqBody requestBody = new GetMyBillingReqBody();
        requestEnvelope.setHeader(requestHeader);
        requestEnvelope.setZbody(requestBody);
        Call<GetMyBillingResEnvelope> responseEnvelopeCall = BhanuSamajApiImpl.getApi().getMyBilling(requestEnvelope);
        responseEnvelopeCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetMyBillingResEnvelope>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetMyBillingResEnvelope> call, Response<GetMyBillingResEnvelope> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        GetMyBillingData data = ((GetMyBillingResEnvelope) response.body()).getBody().getGetMyBillsResponse();


                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        GetMyBillingResponse getMyBillingResponse = new GetMyBillingResponse();
                        getMyBillingResponse = mapper.readValue(data.getGetMyBillsResult().toString(), GetMyBillingResponse.class);

                        itemList.addAll(getMyBillingResponse.getMyBillResponse());
                        mainitemList.addAll(getMyBillingResponse.getMyBillResponse());
                        myBillingAdapter = new MyBillingAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adpt_billing, itemList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myBillingAdapter);

                        selected();


                        if (dialog1.isShowing()) {
                            dialog1.dismiss();
                        }
                        //  Log.d("tag", "CODE ::; " + myProfileResponse.getEmployeeAuth().getCode());
                        Log.d("tag", "response :: " + data.getGetMyBillsResult().toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetMyBillingResEnvelope> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

    }


void selected() {

    edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            String text = edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            filter(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


    });


}
```