# Regarding search option in android

Tags: android

I want to implement the search option for my application,and auto fill option for that search bar.. can any one help to do this..

Comment: If you want local search in your application then check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816677/android-local-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

I've gone through that and implemented local search for my app with search recommendations and  history without problems.